# Python 3 TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes' casperjs_capture

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, casperjs

I am getting error while executing below code with python 3 but on python 2 it is working fine

```
template_content = <HTML data>
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html') as render_file:
    render_file.write(template_content.encode('utf-8'))
    render_file.seek(0)
    stream = StringIO()
    casperjs_capture(stream, url='file://%s' % os.path.abspath(render_file.name))
```

Error:

```
*** TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just changes from StringIO to BytesIO and its work for me. To find the solution, it almost take a day

```
template_content = <HTML data>
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html') as render_file:
    render_file.write(template_content.encode('utf-8'))
    render_file.seek(0)
    stream = BytesIO()
    casperjs_capture(stream, url='file://%s' % os.path.abspath(render_file.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

The file object returned by `NamedTemporaryFile()` is apparently in text mode, so you should not encode `template_content` into bytes before writing to `render_file`.

Change:

```
render_file.write(template_content.encode('utf-8'))
```

to:

```
render_file.write(template_content)
```